# Chronological ordering of checkbox in Google Forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a checkbox in my Google Form, which sends the user selections in the form in an ascending order list:

[image: image_one]

But I want to grab the list in the order of selection, for example if the user clicks in the order of **Option 4, Option 1, Option 10** the cell should show **Option 4, Option 1, Option 10**.

I've tried to do it using Google App Script, but could not get it done. Any help would be much appreciated.

*Note: I'm very new to this, so kindly provide a brief explanation.*

Comment: *I've tried to do it via Google App Scripting*  Show your code, tell us what went wrong specifically (error messages?)

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions offered? Did any work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script doesn't have any objects/methods to handle Google Forms view (respondent view) and the order of selection isn't an attribute that is included on the response submission.

If that is a must, then you should look for another app or build your own web form.

Answer (score 1):

**To preserve the order the selections are made without resorting to another app or creating your own web form** (as stated at Rubén's correct answer), another (*easier maybe?*) alternative would be to:

1. Add a "Title and description" above the question
2. Change the type of your question from "Checkboxes" to "Paragraph"

[image]